# How do I modify a .sln file with Yeoman?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, sln-file

I am using [**Yeoman**](http://yeoman.io/) to create new projects in my Visual Studio solution. I can already generate .csproj and source files, but I can't figure out an easy way to register the project in the solution.

.sln files are not XML, they have their own format. I would need to insert something like this in two sections of the file:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "MyCoolComponent", "\MyCoolComponent\code\MyCoolComponent.csproj", "{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}"
EndProject
```

...

```
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Debug|x64.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Debug|x64.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Release|x64.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
{709C3622-1F4D-417C-9103-3882154ACBFD}.Release|x64.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
```

Is there, perhaps, a NodeJS library that can help me with modifying .sln files?

Comment: Great question, I have the same question, did you ever find a way?

Comment: @DylanYoung I just used regular expressions. Take a look here: https://github.com/metro-nom/generator-sitecore-sxa/blob/master/generators/app/index.js#L94,L149